# What is -D option in yarn when adding vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js, yarnpkg

When adding vuetify in [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start) it says to add -D option.

```
@nuxtjs/vuetify -D
```

What is it for? Is it something related `vuetify` or `yarn`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to yarn, actually. This flag defines that the installed package will be added to your **devDependencies** at your **package.json** file. These are your development dependencies. Dependencies that you need at some point in the development workflow but not while running your code (e.g. Babel or Flow).

After the yarn build process, the entire Vue project is compiled in vanillaJS with the help of vuetify. So, the vuetify package isn't needed on a production build as it is only needed while compiling the project. That's why it is advised to install vuetify as a devDependency.

Comment: Any idea why vuetify is  installed only on development mode as per the docs?

Comment: After the yarn build process, the entire Vue project is compiled in vanillaJS with the help of vuetify. So, the vuetify package isn't needed on a production build as it is only needed while compiling the project. That's why it is advised to install vuetify as a devDependency.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It would be useful for someone if you can update the last comment in the provided answer